# Azure SQL Datawarehouse JDBC Connectivity

Tags: azure, jdbc, azure-synapse, datagrip, sql-workbench-j

Asking here as a last resort, we've been having many issues trying to connect to Azure SQL DW from a non-Windows environment (Linux, Mac) where SQL Server Managment Studio (SSMS) is not an option.

The core requirement is a GUI for analysis (DataGrip, SQLWorkbench/J, DBeaver, etc..)

Using SQLWorkbench/J, JDK 8 and sqljdbc42.jar with the following connection string taken from Azure Portal:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://<server_name>.database.windows.net:1433;database=<db_name>;user=<user_name>@<server_name>;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;
```

In SQLWorkbench/J we're getting the following error:

```
Parse Error at line 5, column 28: Incorrect syntax near '(' [SQL State: S0001, DB Errorcode: 13010]
```

DataGrip just hangs when trying to load a schema/tables.

So currently we have no way of connecting via a non-Windows environment to  SQL DW, has anyone encountered this and has a workaround?

Comment: I can see what you're saying about DataGrip but I've gotten other services to run. Have you tried SQuirrel SQL?

Comment: Do you use DataGrip 2016.3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tried to comment, but we use DBeaver with great success to work with Azure SQL Data Warehouse.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SQL Data Warehouse is now supported in Visual Studio Code (as of April 12, 2017). You'll need to download the mssql extension. Visual Studio Code is cross platform so it should benefit those in a non-Windows environment.